# Changing "skin" and fonts in Gramps Windows All-In-One (AIO)?

Tags: gramps

Is it possible to change the “skin” and fonts in Gramps Windows All-In-One (AIO)?

I'd like to see more data by making the font smaller. I also think the buttons and graphics in the latest version are too big.

How can I change the font, button, and graphics size?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot customize the fonts and appearance within Gramps itself, but it is quite straighforward to modify the GTK theme settings.

For the latest version for Windows (4.2.1), find the config file. Go to the base path for Gramps in Program Files > etc > gtk-3.0 > settings.ini

Open up the settings.ini and add or change a line:

```
gtk-font-name = Arial 8
```

(or whatever font and size you want).

Making this change alone I found the buttons to scale to an appropriate size.

You can also modify other aspects of the theme by browsing the style files in the themes folder.

Keep in mind it would be a good idea to document what you change, because if you update to a later version all these changes will revert, and if you're like me you'll struggle to remember exactly what settings you changed before.

Answer (score 2):

In order to request Gramps software changes I recommend that you contact its developers via the **[Gramps Project Contact Page](https://gramps-project.org/contact/)**.

It says there that:

> Requesting an enhancement can be done either through the gramps-users
>   or gramps-devel mailing lists, or by creating a feature item on the
>   bug tracker.

Answer (score -2):

I have puzzled through a process which works for me to set the GRAMPS V5 font in Windows. You can also tweak the appearance if you know how to adjust GTK themes.

I wrote it up as a blog post on [How to Change the Font for GRAMPS on Windows](https://fire-eggs.github.io/change_gramps_font.html).

Comment: Hi, Kevin, please include the information in your answer here instead of simply linking to your blog post. You might use as your model the answer on your question https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/12438/1006 where Louis Kessler linked to blog posts but gave enough information in his answer that the answer is complete without it.